# Unity AnimationEvent has no reciever

Tags: unity-game-engine, android-animation

Here are the two Error messages I am receiving.
This seems to only happen when the Run animation is playing. Any help would be appreciated. 
I am building this game for android and I am using mouse clicks to move the character. Since mouse clicks translate to touch events this should have no barring on the game as far as I know.
I guess I should also note that the animations play fine while playing the game.

```
'defaultModelfbx' AnimationEvent 'FootL' has no receiver! Are you missing a component?

'defaultModelfbx' AnimationEvent 'FootR' has no receiver! Are you missing a component?

using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    float speed = 10;
    float rotSpeed = 5;
    Vector3 targetPosition;
    Vector3 lookAtTarget;
    Quaternion playerRot;
    bool moving = false;
    Animator thisAnim;


    void Update()
    {
        thisAnim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        // Get movement of the finger since last frame
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
           SetTargetPosition();
        }

        if (moving)
        {
            Move();
        }
    }

    void SetTargetPosition()
    {
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit hit;

        if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 1000))
        {

            targetPosition = hit.point;
            lookAtTarget = new Vector3(targetPosition.x - `transform.position.x, 0, targetPosition.z - transform.position.z);`
            playerRot = Quaternion.LookRotation(lookAtTarget);
            moving = true;
        }

    }

    void Move()
    {
        thisAnim.SetFloat("speed", 1);
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, playerRot, rotSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetPosition, speed * Time.deltaTime);

        if (transform.position == targetPosition)
        {
            moving = false;
            thisAnim.SetFloat("speed", 0);
        }
    }
}
```

[image: AnimationEvent Error]

Comment: Does your animation has any events on it? It's like a little white pin over the timeline: [AnimationEvents](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/animeditor-AnimationEvents.html)

Comment: Thank you so much I have found both events

Comment: Yes please add your own answer as well. I am sure you can add more detail as far as created needed event functions.

Comment: You answer is good, I don't have much more to add! I think it's enough for those with the same problem (:

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error, but with a different cause and solution.

All my code was in a (grand)parent gameobject (e.g. WerewolfPlayer) and I wanted to keep it this way. The animator was in a (grand)child gameobject (e.g. WEREWOLF_PBR) and it couldn't find the animation events:
[image]

To fix this, I bubbled-up the event from the child gameobject to the parent:
[image]

I edited the PlayerController.cs in the parent gameobject (e.g. WerewolfPlayer) to find the new "hand off animation events" script and fire the animation events when they happen:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private HandOffAnimationEvent handOffAnimationEvent;

    // called when animation event fires
    public void Pickup()
    {
        Debug.Log("player picks up object here...");
    }

    void OnEnable()
    {
        handOffAnimationEvent = GetComponentInChildren<HandOffAnimationEvent>();
        handOffAnimationEvent.OnPickup += Pickup;
    }

    void OnDisable()
    {
        handOffAnimationEvent.OnPickup -= Pickup;
    }
}
```

The new HandOffAnimationEvents.cs was added to the child gameobject (e.g. WEREWOLF_PBR) and when the animation event fires, it fires its own event:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;

public class HandOffAnimationEvent : MonoBehaviour
{
    public event Action OnPickup;

    // This is the animation event, defined/called by animation
    public void Pickup()
    {
        OnPickup?.Invoke();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay thanks to Nathalia Soragge I have found the solution to the problem.
If you look closely at the animation window you can see two white dashes at the top of the time line. I have clicked on one of them in the picture, and sure enough it is one of the events that were throwing the error message.
I am assuming I can just delete these two events since I do not have them anywhere in code. In this case it is looking for the events in my PlayerController since it is attached to my Model defaultModelfbx

UPDATE: I have deleted both events and now everything is running smoothly. Thanks again Nathalia!!!!!!! ;)

[image: Events Found]

Comment: No problem, glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to listen to any events, you can set `Animator.fireEvents` to false.

```cs
public Animator animator;

void Start() 
{
    animator.fireEvents = false;
}
```

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator-fireEvents.html

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.I solved this by deleting all animation events and recreating all of them again.